# Install docker-machine on OSX WITHOUT Docker Toolbox

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

Am I correct to assume that installing Docker Toolbox is now the required method for installing docker-machine on OSX? I have a script that I've been using for onboarding my team of developers, which installs docker related tools like docker-machine, but it pulls it in through curl. This stopped working with the latest version. All their documentation says I need to install Docker Toolbox, with no indication of an alternative. Is there still a way to install it through the command line?

Answer (score 5):

I installed virtualbox, docker, docker-machine and docker-compose all via [homebrew](http://brew.sh), and worked like a charm to me.

```
$ brew install docker docker-compose docker-machine
```

if you don't have installed virtualbox, you could install it using [homebrew cask](http://caskroom.io).

```
$ brew cask install virtualbox
```

One important thing you obtain when you installing it this way, is the bash completion. You need to install bash-completion, previously, for this benefit.

```
$ brew install bash-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. It's undocumented, but if you go to their github page, then click on releases, you'll see all the latest releases for the OS you're looking for. https://github.com/docker/machine/releases. Find the download you need, then run this:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.4.0/docker-machine_darwin-amd64 > /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install it also with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

`$ brew install docker-machine`